# Cannot update mysql table in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sql-update

I have a form that the user can edit and save anytime. When the user changes a value in the form, the database updates successfully. However when no changes have been made and the user clicks save, the form should still update successfully but it alerts "Failed to update".

Regardless if there are changes or none, the form should still save. What should I do?

Here's my code.

```
$orderID = $_POST["orderID"];
$clientsName = $_POST["clientsName"];

 $result = $wpdb->update('wp_orderrecords', 
                array(
                       'orderID' => $orderID,
                       'clientsName' => $clientsName),
                array('orderID' =>$orderID),
                array('%d', 
                      '%s'),
                array('%d')); 

if($result){
       echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
             window.alert('You have successfully updated this sales order.')
                  </SCRIPT>");
} else{
  var_dump( $wpdb->last_query );
       echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                  window.alert('You have failed to update this sales order.');
                  </SCRIPT>");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method `update` returns the number of rows updated, or false if there is an error. Keep in mind that if the $data matches what is already in the database, no rows will be updated, so 0 will be returned. Because of this, you should probably check the return with false === $result.

```
if($result === false){
    //Show error
}else {
   //Show success
}
```